# PHPStorm / IntelliJ how to control how an object is displayed in the debugger

Tags: php, debugging, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I am debugging PHP code in PHPStorm (a stripped down version of IntelliJ).
When I inspect a `Zend_Date` instance in the debugger it prints only the instance fields, which include the unix timestamp, e.g.

```
*Zend_Date_DateObject*_unixTimestamp = 1372870800
```

This object has a much more human readable view if I add a watch and cast it to a string:

```
(string)$dateVal = "3 Jul 2013 18:00:00"
```

How can I get a display more like the latter without having to "add watch", then "edit watch" and add "(string)" on every Date object I encounter?